Symbolism of the word "face" in Grace Paley short story
Within "A Conversation With My Father", the narrator — an author like Paley — recounts a conversation with her bedridden father that she has been taking care of. He asks her to write a story, and she returns with a story about a narrator with neighbor that is a drug addict. The neighbor has a single mother that decides to also begin using in an attempt to connect and bond with him. Eventually, the son is disgusted by this prospect and moves out, leaving the mother to grieve alone.
Her father appears to be deeply troubled by the quality and presentation of her story. He fires off demands for her to provide more details. He berates her, claiming that "[t]here are in fact [...] writers you have never heard of, you don't have an inkling of, as good as anyone, who can write a plain good story." The narrator notes that he had "been a doctor" and "an artist" for "a couple of decades", and was thus a man dedicated to "details, craft, [and] technique". She dutifully complies and fleshes out a more complete story.
However, her father remains unsatisfied and continues to criticize her story, now nitpicking at the ending of the story. The phrase "look it in the face" is repeated twice by the father. The first time as their argument begins to heat up.

In your own life, too, you have to look it in the face.” He took a couple of nitroglycerin. “Turn to five,” he said, pointing to the dial on the oxygen tank. He inserted the tubes into his nostrils and breathed deep.

It is repeated again at the final line of the story.

“How long will it be?” he asked. “Tragedy! You too. When will you look it in the face?”

I am wondering what is meant by this line. I don't believe Paley would repeat this line twice, and end with it, if it didn't have some other special meaning.
In the context of the story, I am guessing that at a literal level it means that her father finds her daughter's story to be so bad and embarrassing enough that it causes him to lose face. Ulff (2015) does not directly analyze the phrase in his peer-reviewed article in the JSSE, but it is implied that he instead interprets it as the father 'urging his daughter to face the “tragic” dimension of existence'. Though, I am sure it really is the stress from her father's medical predicament, perhaps exacerbated by the tragic self-awareness of ironically having been a doctor, that is actually causing him to lash out and take it out on his daughter. The entire story seems to dance around this concept without actually mentioning it.
However, outside the story, I am very curious what symbolism Paley is possibly employing and trying to say at a thematic level by repeating this phrase.
The short story reads very poignantly and the idea of embedding a story into another story is quite novel, so I would imagine that Paley has put some thought into choosing her words.
